# Sql server connections for multiple users

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Probably easy answer to that but just to make sure. I am developing multi user application which will be used with Sql Server database, so every user will be sitting with his application copy on the desk. My question is aabout connection string - user login inside. Should i create for each user application diffrent login (user) in connection string or there could be one same for all users applications? Would like to avoid situation when one user blocking other one during usage of same connection string's user login. How this should be done?

Comment: One user using the same login as someone else will not block per se. Having a slow query running on any logon might do though

Comment: See also [best practices when using ado.net](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements#t=201608021320122972941) (connecting to a sql server database from .net). The example is written in c# but it is still applicable even in vb.net. As Matt pointed out multiple connections will not block each other based only on the execution context (user name).

Comment: so that does means i can stay with one user login in connection string for all application instances right? And second question is it more like to make all queries using transaction to avoid issues with data (crud) for multi queries and for single queries not required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that you would have to create different users logins for different users. I have been using a single login for the past few years with more than 5 users and they still work perfectly fine.